# Who else is Hob Gadling referring to?

Tags: comics, vertigo-comics, the-sandman

In the Dolls House part 4 'Men of Good Fortune', in the Nineteenth Century Hob Gadling refers to 2 other people who cannot die.

One of these is Mad Hettie, (I am assuming), a fictional character that Neil Gaiman uses many times throughout the "The Sandman" story arc, however the other Hob refers to only as 'Blood'.

Assuming that this is some other historical or literary reference, does anyone know who this refers to?

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a (DC) reference to [Jason Blood](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Jason_Blood_(New_Earth)).

> *Jason Blood is a world leading expert on the occult and demonology. He has walked the Earth since the 6th Century, after the wizard Merlin bound the increasingly uncontrollable threat of Etrigan The Demon to his mortal soul.*

We met his *host* (the demon Etrigan) a few issues earlier in [*Sandman: Master of Dreams - A Hope in Hell*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Sandman_Vol_2_4) but to the best of my knowledge we never meet Jason.

[image]

Comment: Ah, brilliant. Well done and thank you! Readin the wiki on him, it would explain why Hob says that he doesn't always remember him!

Comment: @FrancisG.Maitland since the post answered your question, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)